# Why are flip and flip(:) different functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> :t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
Prelude> :t flip(:)
flip(:) :: [a] -> a -> [a]
```

I don't think `(:)` is a special syntactic sugar for `flip`. So what has it done to `flip`?

Comment: `flip(:)` is `flip` with `(:)` as function, so you here see `b -> a -> [c]` but specialized according with the type parameters of `(:)`.

Comment: I forgot that `(:)` is also a function. Thank you very much!

Comment: “_Also_ a function”? What else _but_ a function is it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think the "also" refers to "`(:)`", not to "function" -- as in, "`flip` is a function, and also `(:)` is a function", not "`(:)` is a function, and also `(:)` is an X".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "ingredients" are:

```
flip :: (a -> (b -> c)) -> (b -> (a -> c))
(:) :: d -> ([d] -> [d])
```

So here `flip` can take a function (of type `a -> b -> c`), and it basically converts it to a function of type `b -> a -> c`, where thus the "parameters" (technically speaking in Haskell a function has *exactly* one parameter) are "flipped".

If you write `flip (:)`, you thus flip the `(:)` function. Since the `(:)` function has type `d -> [d] -> [d]`, the result is `[d] -> d -> [d]`.

We can however perform a more rigorous type inference. Since `(:)` is the parameter of a function application with `flip`, we know that the type of `(:)` should be the same as the type of the *parameter* of `flip`, so:

```
   a -> ( b  -> c  )
~  d -> ([d] -> [d])
-----------------------
a ~ d, b ~ [d], c ~ [d]
```

So we conclude that `a ~ d` (`a` and `d` are the same type), `b ~ c ~ [d]`. This thus means that the type of `flip (:)` is:

```
flip (:) :: b -> a -> c
```

or when we perform the replacements to more specific types:

```
flip (:) :: [d] -> d -> [d]
```

Semantically `flip (:)` takes a list `xs`, and an element `x`, and returns a list where the element is *prepended* to the given list (so `(x:xs)`).

Answer (score 3):

`flip (:)` is an application of `flip` and `(:)`.

Their types are

```
Prelude> :t flip
flip ::   (a ->  b  ->  c ) -> ( b  -> a ->  c )
Prelude> :t (:)
(:)  ::    a -> [a] -> [a]
Prelude> :t flip (:)
flip (:) ::                     [a] -> a -> [a]
```

`flip` just switches the two arguments to a function:

```
flip f y x = f x y
```

Thus

```
flip (:) xs x = (:) x xs = x : xs
```